# Dijkstra's Algorithm With Large Weights

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, dijkstra, adjacency-list

I am trying to solve a question on an online judge about calculating all shortest paths on a complete graph. Full problem specifications can be seen  [here.](https://dmoj.ca/problem/dmopc15c3p4) However, I am exceeding the memory limit required. Here is the part of the code that does Dijkstra's algorithm:

```
n = int(raw_input())
dict1 = [[""for i in xrange(n+1)]for j in xrange(n+1)]
edges = [0]
for i in xrange(n):
    x,y = map(int, raw_input().split())
    edges.append((x,y))

for i,coord1 in enumerate(edges):
    for j,coord2 in enumerate(edges):
        if i==j or i==0 or j==0:
            continue

        x1,y1 = coord1
        x2,y2 = coord2
        weight = (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2)
        dict1[i][j] = weight
        dict1[j][i] = weight

x = int(raw_input())
times = []
vertices = {i:1e13 if i!= x else 0 for i in xrange(1,n+1)}
while len(vertices)>0:
    minimum = min(vertices.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
    currentCost = vertices[minimum]
    times.append(currentCost)
    del vertices[minimum]

    for neighbour,newWeight in enumerate(dict1[minimum]):
        if neighbour in vertices and newWeight != "":
            if currentCost + newWeight < vertices[neighbour]:
                vertices[neighbour] = currentCost + newWeight
```

The code uses the original algorithm without the priority queue because of the better time complexity. Even though this gives the right answer, I have a feeling the memory exceeding has something to do with the way I am storing the weights, considering they can be as large as 10^12. Is there another way I can store the weights that will use less memory, or is something else causing the problem?

Comment: If `dict1[i][j] = weight`==`dict1[j][i] = weight` do not store both, but change the code to switch `[i][j]` at retrieval when required.

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen I was thinking about that, but it would require a lot of modifications in the while loop, which might cause the code to go over the time limit. Also, I think that these numbers cant actually be stored easily in another language such as c++ due to their size, so i think the issue is the way how I'm representing the weights.

Comment: Only thinking of more code changes: It becomes faster and uses less memory if you do not calculate `dict1` at all until required: create a function for lookup and if not present calculating `dict1[minimum]`. That will reduce the calculations to only the required rows of `dict1` reducing both memory and time required. Worst case scenario is equal time to what you have now.

Comment: You can use a Delaunay triangulation to limit the number of candidate "shortest path" edges at the start, if your problem lends itself to that (roads, etc.). Also, the best Python implementation of this that I have seen is in http://www.apress.com/9781430232377.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Yes, I think calculating each weight in the loop instead of storing them is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with big weights (`10^12` is not a big number). If you want to see that this is the case (try dividing them by some number like `1000` to see that it will fail as well).

The problem is that you do not use priority queue and this deteriorate the time complexity to `O(V^2)` and if you will use a priority queue, you will get `O(E + V log(V))`.

So implement a normal Dijkstra and will get your answer accepted.

---

Sorry, have not read that this is a planar graph and that it is dense. Knowing that your graph consists of 2d points, you can take advantage of the distance heuristics and use [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: It's a complete graph though, so this causes time limit problems due to the   O(V^2 log(V)) of doing an extractmin on each edge in the queue.

Comment: @BobMarshall you are right. Have not seen that. Knowing that your graph is planar, you can use A* algorithm. I updated the answer. But still the big weights have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I think the idea was to calculate the weights on the fly instead of storing them in a list.